# Why am I getting 1 as result after using "i" as my array index?

Tags: java, arrays

I've made a class named Car with methods that should resemble some functions of a real car. I'm trying to get the car's **number** of both the heaviest car and smallest car's engine.

As shown in my code below, you can see that I've done the validation using an index and then comparing that to "i". However, no matter what number I enter, I get "1" as result on both validations.

What could be wrong? I should be getting the number of the car instead of just "1".

Here is my **code to get the heaviest car**:

```
int weight = x[i].getweight();
if(weight > max) {
    maxweight = weight;
    maxIndex = i;
}
```

My **Car** class:

```
public class Car
{
    private String color;
    private int weight;
    private int state;
    private int fuel;
    private int Maxspeed ;
    private int engine;

    public Car() {
        this.color = "White";
        this.weight = 1000;
        this.state = 0;
        this.fuel =0;
        this.Maxspeed = 0;
        this.engine = 0;
    }

    public Car (String color, int weight,
            int state, int fuel, int Maxspeed 
            ) {
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.state = state;
        this.fuel = fuel;
        this.Maxspeed = Maxspeed;
    }

    public String getColor() { return this.color; }

    public int getweight() { return this.weight; } 

    public int getstate() { return this.state; }

    public int getfuel() { return this.fuel; }

    public int getMaxspeed() { return this.Maxspeed; }

    public int getengine() { return this.engine; }


    public void setColor( String color ){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setweight( int weight ){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setstate( int state ){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setfuel( int fuel ){
        this.fuel = fuel;
    }

    public void setMaxspeed( int Maxspeed ){
        this.Maxspeed = Maxspeed;
    }

    public void setengine(int engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public void showdata() {
        System.out.println( "\nCar's color is: " + this.getColor() );
        System.out.println( "Car's weight is: " + this.getweight() );
        System.out.println( "State: " + this.getstate() );
        System.out.println( "Fuel: " + this.getfuel());
        System.out.println( "Max speed: "  + this.getMaxspeed());
    }

    public void accelerate( int speed ){
        if( this.getstate() == 0 || this.getstate() == 3 || 
            this.getstate() == 4 || this.getMaxspeed() < speed )
        {
            System.out.println("\nCar cannot accelerate...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nCar is accelerating...");
            this.setfuel(this.getfuel()-2);
            this.setstate(2);
            if( this.getfuel() <= 0 ) {
                this.setstate(4);
            }
        }
    }

    public void crash() {
        this.setstate(3);
        System.out.println("\nCrash!!!");
    }
    public void stop() {
        this.setstate(1);
        System.out.println("\nCar has stopped.");
    }

   public void addfuel(int fuel) {
        if(this.getstate() == 0 || this.getstate() == 4){
            this.setfuel(this.getfuel()+ fuel);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You can't add fuel.");
        }
    }

    public void repair() {
        if(this.getstate() == 3){
           this.setstate(1);
           System.out.println("The car has been repaired");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("The car is not broken");
        } 
    }
}
```

My **Main**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class aaa {
    public static void main (String args []) {    
        Car x[] = new Car[2];
        int keep=1;
        int counter = 0;
        int counter_stopped = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int maxweight = 0;
        int index_engine = 0;
        int min_engine = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            String color;
            int weight;
            int fuel;
            int Maxspeed;
            int engine;

            x[i] = new Car();

            System.out.print("\nEnter car color " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            color = input.next();

            System.out.print("Enter car weight " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            weight = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter car fuel " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            fuel = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter car max speed " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            Maxspeed = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter car engine weight " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            engine = input.nextInt();


            x[i].setColor(color);
            x[i].setweight(weight);
            x[i].getstate();
            x[i].setfuel(fuel);
            x[i].setMaxspeed(Maxspeed);
            x[i].setengine(engine);
        }        

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            int state;

            System.out.print("\nEnter car state " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            state = input.nextInt();
            x[i].setstate(state);

            while(state > 4 || state < 0){
                System.out.print("state not valid.\nTry again: ");
                state = input.nextInt();
                x[i].setstate(state);
            }

            do {
                keep = menu();

                switch( keep ) {
                case 1:
                    accelerate(x[i]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    stop(x[i]);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    crash(x[i]);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    addfuel(x[i]);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    repair(x[i]);
                    break;      

                case 6:
                    x[i].showdata();
                }
            } while(keep != 7);   

            if(x[i].getstate() == 4 || x[i].getfuel() <= 0){
                counter += 1;
            }

            if(x[i].getstate() == 1){
                counter_stopped += 1;
            }

            int weight = x[i].getweight();
            if(weight > max){
                maxweight = weight;
                maxIndex = i;
            }

            int weightengine = x[i].getengine();
            if(weightengine < min){
                min_engine = weightengine;
                index_engine = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nSUMMARY");
        System.out.println("Amount of cars with no fuel: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Amount of stopped cars: " + counter_stopped);
        System.out.println("Heaviest car: " + maxIndex);
        System.out.println("Car with the smallest engine: " + index_engine);
        System.out.println("=============================================");
    }

    public static int menu() {
      int option = 0;
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("\n1. Accelerate Car ");
      System.out.println("2. Stop Car ");
      System.out.println("3. Crash Car ");
      System.out.println("4. Add fuel ");
      System.out.println("5. Repair ");
      System.out.println("6. Show data ");
      System.out.println("7. Exit ");
      System.out.println("=============================================");
      System.out.print("Choose an option : ");
      option = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("=============================================");
      return option;
    } 

    public static void accelerate(Car myCar){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        int s;

        System.out.print("Enter speed: ");
        s =  input.nextInt();
        myCar.accelerate(s);
        //myCar.showdata();
    }

    public static void stop(Car myCar){
        myCar.stop();
    }

    public static void crash(Car myCar){
        myCar.crash();
    }

    public static void addfuel(Car myCar){
        int fuel;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.print("Amount to add: ");
        fuel = input.nextInt();
        myCar.addfuel(fuel);
    }

    public static void repair(Car myCar){
        myCar.repair();
    }
}
```

Now, when I compile and test which engine or car is smaller or heaviest, I get the number 1 as result.

Comment: What have you already tried to debug this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking.  I don't know which code is the "validate" that is displaying the wrong output, and your program is too big for me to go hunting through it to figure out what you're talking about.  Please tell us specifically what line is displaying the wrong output.

Comment: I've just updated with the code I use to get the heaviest of the cars. It's on my "main" and under my 2nd "for"

Comment: Asking the same badly formed question twice doesn't make your question any better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678463/how-to-print-the-array-index-of-an-object-class/30678607#30678607 Please do some work for your self and just run your code in a debugger.

Comment: Advice for the future: please post the smallest amount of code possible which can reproduce your problem.

Comment: It did. I got the answer I needed and learned a new way of getting min and max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious issue is

```
if(weight > max){
    maxweight = weight;
```

You are comparing `max` and `weight`, but then seeting `maxweight`. Also, I suggest you prefer [`Math.max(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) and [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) like

```
max = Math.max(max, weight);
min = Math.min(min, weight);
```

**Edit** To store the index of the `min` and `max` value you could initialize `max` and `min` to `0` and loop from index `1` to `x.length`. That might look something like

```
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].getweight() > x[max].getweight) {
        max = i;
    } else if (x[i].getweight() < x[min].getweight) {
        min = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I use that?

Comment: By replacing your `if`(s) with the code I gave you. It would set `max` and `min` based on the `weight`.

Comment: It returns the weight of the heaviest car, I want to return the number of the heaviest car... that's why I thought using "i" wold give me the number of the car in the array.

Comment: @Midori_hige I didn't realize you wanted the index... added an edit above.

Comment: Alright, now it works! To use the same "for" loop I had to add "1" to the "i" and then it gave me the correct car's number. Thanks